# Str.replace in python doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, pandas

my problem is pretty straightforward. the column names of my dataframe include their source but i'd like to take it out to make it simpler.

df.columns brings back

```
 Index(['a_(Source:_WaPo)','b_(Source:_WaPo)','c_(Source:_WaPo)'],
      dtype='object')
```

so what I did was

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('_(Source:_WaPo)','')
```

self assignment didn't seem to do anything *(i'm working in jupyter notebook)* so I tried just doing it without the self assignment to see what it'd look like

```
df.columns.str.replace('_(Source:_WaPo)','')
```

but the columns didn't change at all.

Is there an alternate way of doing this? or am I doing it wrong in any way? any help would be appreciated.

This is just an example, so let's say I have a lot of columns, and I wouldn't want to just manually replace each of them.

Comment: @Ira you can try this too `df.columns.str.replace('_(Source:_WaPo)','',regex=False)`, by default `regex` parameter is set to `True` and in regex `(...)` is a capture group.

Comment: ill try it out, thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

Code below replaces the text:

```
df.columns.str.replace(r"_\(Source:_WaPo\)","")
```

or

```
df.columns = [x.replace("_(Source:_WaPo)","") for x in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually from df.columns you got list and list does have function have replace. Instead you have to iterate over the list in which your column names are present where you can easily replace string.

```
df.columns = [column.replace("_(Source:_WaPo","") for column in df.columns]
```